# How to provide a shader function to perform the alpha masking for video

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, vertex-shader, glsurfaceview

[image][image]I am working on Vr app using virocore library in android. I have to show video over sphere. The video which i have to implement is not actually video but the two frames provided are the colour frame (left) and the alpha mask (right) frame. I have not worked with openGl but seems like I will need to provide a shader function to perform the alpha masking.

I have used this for shader [Adding transparency to a video from black and white (and gray) alpha information video images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066828/adding-transparency-to-a-video-from-black-and-white-and-gray-alpha-information)

but how can i use it with OpenGL in on draw method? or If there is any way in virocore using which i can do alpha masking. I have tried chroma filtering method in virocore but that makes whole video transparent.

```
public class VideoSurfaceView   extends GLSurfaceView {

VideoRender mRenderer;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

public VideoSurfaceView(Context context, MediaPlayer mp) {
    super(context);

    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    mMediaPlayer = mp;
    mRenderer = new VideoRender(context);

    this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
    this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    setRenderer(mRenderer);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.e("onResume ", "onResume");
    queueEvent(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            Log.e("runnable ", "runnable");
            mRenderer.setMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer);
        }});

    super.onResume();
}

private static class VideoRender
        implements Renderer, SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    private static String TAG = "VideoRender";

    private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;
    private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
            // X, Y, Z, U, V
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
    };

    private FloatBuffer mTriangleVertices;


    private static final String mVertexShader =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
                    "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
            "attribute vec4 position;\n" +
            "attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;\n" +
            " \n" +
            "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" +
            "varying vec2 textureCoordinate2;\n" +
            " \n" +
            "void main()\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * position;\n" +
            "    vec4 texCoord = uSTMatrix * inputTextureCoordinate;\n"+

                    "textureCoordinate  = vec2(inputTextureCoordinate.x * 0.5, inputTextureCoordinate.y);\n" +
  "   textureCoordinate2 = vec2(inputTextureCoordinate.x * 0.5 + 0.5, inputTextureCoordinate.y);\n" +
            "}";


    public static final String mFragmentShader = "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n"+
            "varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;\n"+
            "varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2;\n"+
            "uniform samplerExternalOES inputImageTexture;\n" +
            "void main() {\n"+
            "    lowp vec4 rgbcolor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);\n"+
            "    lowp vec4 alphaValue = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate2);\n"+
            "    if (alphaValue.g < 0.5)\n"+
            "    discard;\n"+
            "    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgbcolor.rgb, 1.0);\n"+
            "}";

    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mSTMatrix = new float[16];

    private int mProgram;
    private int mTextureID;
    private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
    private int muSTMatrixHandle;
    private int maPositionHandle;
    private int maTextureHandle;

    private SurfaceTexture mSurface;
    private boolean updateSurface = false;

    private static int GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = 0x8D65;

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    public VideoRender(Context context) {
        mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                mTriangleVerticesData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);

        Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);

    }

    public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer player) {
        mMediaPlayer = player;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (updateSurface) {
                mSurface.updateTexImage();
                mSurface.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
                updateSurface = false;
            }
        }

        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, .0f);
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
        checkGlError("glUseProgram");

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);

        mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
        checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
        checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

        mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
        checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
        checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

        Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
        GLES20.glFinish();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
        mProgram = createProgram(mVertexShader, mFragmentShader);
        if (mProgram == 0) {
            return;
        }
        maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "position");
        checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
        if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
        }
        maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "inputTextureCoordinate");
        checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
        if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
        }

        muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
        if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
        }

        muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix");
        checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix");
        if (muSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix");
        }


        int[] textures = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

        mTextureID = textures[0];
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
        checkGlError("glBindTexture mTextureID");

        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

        /*
         * Create the SurfaceTexture that will feed this textureID,
         * and pass it to the MediaPlayer
         */
        mSurface = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureID);
        mSurface.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
        Log.e("surface ", "surface");
        Surface surface = new Surface(mSurface);
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
        mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        surface.release();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        synchronized(this) {
            updateSurface = false;
        }
    }

    synchronized public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        updateSurface = true;
    }

    private int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
        if (shader != 0) {
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
            int[] compiled = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
            if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
                Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
                shader = 0;
            }
        }
        return shader;
    }

    private int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
        if (vertexShader == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
        if (pixelShader == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        if (program != 0) {
            GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
            checkGlError("glAttachShader");
            GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
            checkGlError("glAttachShader");
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
            int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
            if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
                Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
                program = 0;
            }
        }
        return program;
    }

    private void checkGlError(String op) {
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e(TAG, op + ": glError " + error);
            throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}  // End of class VideoRender.
```

}  // End of class VideoSurfaceView.

With this code, video looks inverted

Comment: I have a project which requires exactly the same setup as your example here. However i'm not well versed in OpenGL. Do you have a full example of this that i can learn of? Because in this example a lot of attributes from the shaders don't seem to match what is needed in onDraw and onSurfaceCreated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to discard fragments, then you can use the [`discard`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations) keyword in the [fragment shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader).

e.g. discard all fragments with an alpha value less than 0.5:

```c
void main()
{
    lowp vec4 rgbcolor   = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
    lowp vec4 alphaValue = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate2);

    if (alphaValue.g < 0.5)
        discard;   

    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgbcolor.rgb, 1.0);
}
```

See also [OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00 Specification; 6.4 Jumps; page 58](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf):

> The **discard** keyword is only allowed within fragment shaders. It can be used within a fragment shader to abandon the operation on the current fragment. This keyword causes the fragment to be discarded and no updates to any buffers will occur. It would typically be used within a conditional statement, for example:
>
> ```
> if (intensity < 0.0)
>     discard;
> ```

---

In reference to the comment

> As there is no matrix so what will i use in `GLES20.glGetUniformLocation`?

Of course you can add the matrices to the vertex shader:

```c
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate2;

uniform mat4 matMVP;
uniform mat4 matST;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = matMVP * position;

    vec4 texCoord = matST * inputTextureCoordinate;

    textureCoordinate  = vec2(texCoord.x * 0.5,       1.0 - texCoord.y);
    textureCoordinate2 = vec2(texCoord.x * 0.5 + 0.5, 1.0 - texCoord.y);
}
```

```java
muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "matMVP");
muSTMatrixHandle  = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "matST");
```

```java
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);
```